# Is it possible to write a scipt to display packages that haven't been updated in X amount of time?

Tags: scripting, fedora, package-management, ppa

As the title states. I'd like to know if it is possible to write a script which only shows packages which haven't been updated in X amount of time (say 6 months).

The reason I'd like a script like this is to check if packages are unmaintained. I am using Fedora 36, but I reckon this would be particularly useful for people using distros that use PPAs (e.g. Ubuntu, Debian), too, since unmaintained packages may pose a security risk.

Unfortunately, I do not have the skills to write such a script, but if anyone could prod me in the right direction, I'd be more than happy to try and write it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For RPM:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

utnow=$(date +%s)

for i in `rpm -qa`; do
   uti=`rpm -q --queryformat '%{INSTALLTIME}' $i`
   months=$(( (utnow-uti)/86400/30 ))
   if [ $months -ge 6 ]; then
       echo "$i: is $months months old"
   fi
done
```

```
shared-mime-info-2.1-3.fc35.x86_64: is 10 months old
kdocker-5.3-4.fc35.x86_64: is 10 months old
irqbalance-1.7.0-8.fc35.x86_64: is 10 months old
libmodulemd1-1.8.16-6.fc35.x86_64: is 10 months old
```

Comment: Not sure it's possible for APT/DPKG: https://askubuntu.com/questions/790750/get-the-list-of-installed-packages-with-install-time-date-and-vendor-details-wi

Comment: If you don't mind me asking: I see you divided 86400 by 30; I assume that 30 is the amount of days, but what's 86400? 87600 is the amount of hours in 10 years, so it can't be that?

Comment: 60*60*24 = seconds in a day